# Understanding summary of brokerage account value, cash balance, buying power?

Tags: investing, stocks, brokerage, balance

I am totally new to stock and their trading. I have questions when I was trying to understand an account at a brokerage company:

```
Account 12345678(Margin)
Net Liq Value   $23,416.36 
Buying Power - Stock    $27,064.61
Buying Power - Option  $13,532.30
Cash Balance    $3,648.25
Unsettled Cash  $0.00
```

I was wondering

1. what are the meanings of Net Liq Value
   and Cash Balance?
2. What are the meanings of Buying
   Power - Stock, Buying Power -
   Option, and Unsettled Cash?
3. How much money does the account have
   currently?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

- Net Liq Value is the value of the account, if you liquidated all positions right now.
- Cash balance is the value of your cash or money market holdings.
- Stock buying power is the amount of marginable securities that you can buy now.
- Options buying power is the amount of unmarginable securities that you can buy now. You cannot buy options on margin.
- Unsettled cash is the expected proceeds of a sale that is still pending. Some brokers let you use unsettled cash like cash at your own risk.

I'll leave the last question as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks! Is the total money in the account Net Liq Value, or Net Liq Value + Cash balance?

Comment: Net Liq includes cash.