# What is "Stock BP" in a brokerage account that's not trading on margin?

Tags: brokerage, margin

I saw that this question was answered on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/4k2cg7/what_is_the_difference_between_stock_bp_and_cash/) as well as a similar question was answered on this S.X [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/understanding-summary-of-brokerage-account-value-cash-balance-buying-power).

But I wanted to confirm the meaning of a "Stock BP" amount if I'm **not trading on margin** with my brokerage? (I have not done anything to "initiate" any sort of margin account with my brokerage.)

If it helps, this *Stock BP* amount seems to be 3.5% of my account value currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it's because I have an open order worth $XX.XX + brokerage fee which equals this Stock BP amount.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer in your link explains it:

> Your Stock BP (Stock buying power) will indicate how much money you can spend or withdraw right now.